# Creating ActionLink in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm fairly new to MVC so, please excuse my possibly incorrect use of terminology.

In the RouteConfig.cs file of my MVC app there is this routes.MapRoute :-

```
  routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

The key line being :-

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

so, I followed the example of creating ActionLinks, that were created in my default app template, and cobbled together this line :-

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("portfolio details", "Detail", "Portfolio", new { portfolioId = portfolio.PortfolioId } , new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

However, this gives me the URL :-

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Portfolio/Detail?portfolioId=174198
```

If, I don't want the ID to be in a QueryString parameter, how do I create the link to match the pattern that is expected in the routes.MapRoute so that I get a URL link such as :- ?

http://localhost:xxxxx/Portfolio/Detail/174198

Comment: `<p>@Html.ActionLink("portfolio details", "Detail", "Portfolio", new { portfolio.PortfolioId } , new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your controller action has the parameter `id` then you could do:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("portfolio details", "Detail", "Portfolio", new { id = portfolio.PortfolioId } , new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

This should give you:

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Portfolio/Detail/174198
```

The this would pass `174198` to the controller action as the `id` parameter.

Comment: I can only assume you got marked down because of your grammatical faux pas, before this is the solution that gave me the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("portfolio details", string.Format("Detail/{0}", portfolio.PortfolioId ), "Portfolio", null, null)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks messy though, and when I tried to concatenate the id to a string like that in the first instance (before posting) it mangled it and put weird characters in the link.